# input.placeholder text, vertical-aling property

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style my placeholder text and I would like to have the placeholder text to be sitting on top. Its currently sitting in the middle. Padding property works, margin does not, text-align property works, vertical-align does not. Is there a reason for this?

```css
 input[type="textarea"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   padding: 10px;
 }
 input[type="textarea"]:-moz-placeholder {
   /* Firefox 18- */
   padding: 10px;
 }
 input[type="textarea"]::-moz-placeholder {
   /* Firefox 19+ */
   padding: 10px;
 }
 input[type="textarea"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
   padding: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <label>Description</label>
  <input type="textarea" placeholder="Description"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the placeholder above the input box?

Comment: No, I want the placeholder to be vertically aligned top and not middle. The text area is fairly big so it sits in the middle of the vertically and its justified to the left. I would like it to sit in the top left of the textarea box.

Comment: Are talking about `input text`? or `textarea`? Text-area is a different tag.

Comment: We are talking about the placeholder text.

Comment: placeholder where? I have answered it below for text-area. You don't seem to know that `<input type="textarea" />` doesn't exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text area is defined like this : `<textarea rows="4" cols="50">Text here</textarea>`

I think this is what you want :

```html
<div class="description">
  <label>Description</label>
  <textarea placeholder="Describe yourself here..." rows="4" cols="50" ></textarea>
</div>
```